# Facebook Ads API:  What is 'location' parameter in the call for a Reach estimate

Tags: facebook, location

I'm attempting to work with the reachestimation objects defined at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/reachestimate/.

Both the bid estimation and impression estimation that are part of the reach estimate contain an entry for `location` that is given with a simple integer.

I've searched throughout the documentation and can't find any listing of what these numbers correspond to.

Does anyone know where I can find this information and/or what the different values are for?

Comment: Have you tried looking that id up via the Graph API explorer? Maybe that’ll shed some more light on what it is representing. From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs/ I’d guess it could be a specific city or something.

Answer (score 0):

If they're not documented, it's probably a bad idea to rely on them, but it refers to the different locations on Facebook in which the ad will be shown.

I don't know which values correspond to which locations, but presumably one refers to News Feed and one refers to the normal right-hand-side ads bar

Answer (score 0):

You can search for mapping between the location name and the integer by using the [adgeolocation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.3#geo) endpoint. Here's the curl example:

```
curl -G \
  -d "type=adgeolocation" \
  -d "q=Washington" \
  -d "location_types=['city']" \
  -d "access_token=XYZ" \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/search
```

Comment: Once this request returns a list of cities how can I query the coordinates too for a single city?